# is it possible to bind linux executable with server port in python?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, client-server

I have linux executable file, classify input text when executed. To classify the input, it need to read 114MB model file.

Source of package : [www.hlt.utdallas.edu/~altaf/cherrypicker.html](http://www.hlt.utdallas.edu/~altaf/cherrypicker.html)

Though it is opensouce, they have not provided the source code for executable file, So I can not modify it.

Is it possible that I create server socket for this executable which keep `114mb model file` in loaded mode.

So that when I make request as client socket it does not take time and gives instant reply?

I am working on linux and using python programming.

Comment: If the results of the process does not change, you could process the file with the executable you have and save the results in another file or database. Then you could access the saved results in many different ways including a network server. But if the results do change (for any reason, like model file or other factors change), then you'd need to run the executable to get the new results.